# GraphQL errors not logging

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, graphql-js

I am transitioning from jwk endpoint to another and need to make the issuer dynamic. I use graphql that returns and error object that I am trying to capture so that when the error is returned, the old issuer can be used that works.

I believe that graphql returns all as 200 ok so try catch blocks do not capture error. This authentication process happens using expressjwt and jwt libraries and token is generated from postman. I have also tried using next(err) and passing it the error but I am unable to capture it. I appreciate any insight and help